# Issue on Adding Animation to Check Mark

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can add animation to the check Mark?

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
body{padding:20px; }
@-moz-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 50px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 50px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothabottomcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 50px;
}
}
@keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 120px;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 120px;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
dothatopcheck {  0% {
 height: 0;
}
 50% {
 height: 0;
}
 100% {
 height: 120px;
}
}

.check
{
      width: 36px;
  height:36px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  font-size:24px;
  padding-left:7px;


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-1 pop-captcha">
<div class="check">✔</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

mark using pure CSS? I already tried to add

```
  -moz-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
  animation: dothatopcheck 0.4s ease 0s forwards;
```

but this is not doing the job?!

Comment: Do you mean that the check mark should animate on click ?

Comment: Thanks roshan yes but even on load is fine

Comment: You need to describe what type of animation you are looking for. The current code that you have will only animate the box/container of the check mark and not the check mark itself. If that is what you want, add a `overflow: hidden` to `.check` and that should be sufficient. If you are looking to animate the check mark itself then it'd be better for you to use SVG.